# How to communicate HWND to another window for RPC

Tags: c++, windows, rpc

I have 2 Win32 apps: AA and BB.

While app AA is running, app BB can send it Win32 messages via `Send/PostMessage()`. The communication is only from BB->AA.

This is working fine, but there is a problem communicating AA's HWND value to BB. The HWND is an int that Windows(tm) assigns to apps, which they can use for rpc communication. Right now, during development, AA writes its HWND to a log file during startup. I then manually set that number for BB. Now that I got the communication mechanism working, I'd like to automate this exchange of HWND value from AA to BB.

One option is for AA to write a `.pid` file type of thing, which BB can read during startup. But, I'd like to try and avoid that.

Is there a way for AA to publish this HWND integer to a well known place in RAM where BB can look for it? If not, another type of mechanism for sharing that doesn't involve writing the int to a pid file?

Comment: AA can create a named shared memory block called "AA_my_window_handle_here_it_is" and put the HWND in it.

Comment: Use unique window name, which can be found by BB

Comment: For my usecase, I found that the simplest way to go was giving AA a unique "ClassName" and using FindWindowEx() to get the hwnd of AA from BB.